# apple tv crashing whit Focus item does not provide a parentFocusEnvironment

Tags: swift, tvos

in tvOS 16 or higher, i am getting this error.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Focus item <golplustv.TvPagerViewCell: 0x7fba3bab6460> does not provide a parentFocusEnvironment.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.14 - Device: Apple TV (2B02A89D-BCCD-42DB-A4E6-04BD8A09CE60) - Runtime: tvOS 16.1 (20K67) - DeviceType: Apple TV

Someone faced this problem yet? i don't know why this is happening now and the earlier versions works well

My cell didUpdateFocus: (i don't know if the problem is here)

```
public override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    
    if (context.nextFocusedView == self) {
        
        if let viewController = context.nextFocusedView?.parentViewController as? MainViewController {
            
            viewController.pagerView.scrollToItem(at: index, animated: true)

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: ConstantsHelper.pagerViewChanged, object: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the same error. Is there any update ?

Comment: @MetinAtalay tvOS got updated to 16.1 but still the same issue. Still didn't solve it

Comment: I fixed the issue change the button style "card to plain"

Comment: @MetinAtalay I dont have any buttons in my project